# Zend Gdata & Google Spreadsheets - new spreadsheets return 404 not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The new google spreadsheets do not appear in the feed and also, if I use a specific spreadsheetKey, I get a 404 not found error.
Old spreadsheets are fine and work as expected.

Found this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1476

Does anybody else have the same problem? Is there a solution?
I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3 + Zend_Gdata.

Thank you